# psql -c passing in json data

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I'm having trouble passing in some json data to a psql function with the -c option.  I've not written the function, and i'm not in a position to change it.  The usage instructions I was given state to log in via psql and then execute

```
blah.function(('[{"thing":"value","other_thing":"other_value"}]'));
```

This works a treat, however I need to execute it as a oneliner to grab the output and manipulate with with some bash magic.  I've tried all manner of escaping the json data and I get a syntax error every time.

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U user schema -c 'SELECT blah.function(('[{"thing":"value","other_thing":"other_value"}]'));'
```

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U user schema -c 'SELECT blah.function((''[{"thing":"value","other_thing":"other_value"}]''));'
```

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U user schema -c 'SELECT blah.function((\'[{"thing":"value","other_thing":"other_value"}]\'));'
```

Can anyone enlighten me on this monday afternon, how do I pass in the JSON data?

Answer (score 0):

Asked and answered.  The trick was to flip the quotes round and escape the json.  See below

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U user schema -c "SELECT blah.function(('[{\"thing\":\"value\",\"other_thing\":\"other_value\"}]'));"
```

Comment: If you are using Linux/Unix, then a "HERE Doc" would probably be even easier.